# Responsive image - why image in this scenerio is not responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive, responsive-images

thanks for helping!

I set 2 images of -
800X1000

Image 1 :
Set in a  container that set to :
width: 100%.

The image I also set to -
width: 100%

Image 2 :
Set without a container, without any special order.

I set a border to my  container -
And when resizing the screen, to about the 800px mark -
The container started to shrink and didn't take the 100% width I set.
(Therefore , the image is also shrunk).

Once I removed image number 2, it as expected - take the full 100% width of the screen.

Why is that?
Why once I had 2 images inside, the second Image basically cause the  to shrink?

This is my code ( nothing special, 2 CSS lines)

```
.alon  {
    width: 100%;
    border: 5px solid green;
}

.alon img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```
<div class="alon">
       <img src="images/donald.jpg" alt="">
</div>

<img src="images/donald.jpg">
```

HTML above.

Comment: consider share your html as well?

Comment: Please share a working snippet or codepen for good resolution of your problem. Consider adding an image of expected behavior also.

Comment: @Mr.Brickowski I shared my html.

Its really standart.

just a 
<div class="alon">
<img>
</div>

<img>

Answer (score 0):

Your second image has no styling, you basically just dropped an image in the body container and never specified a width for it.

With the code you provided, the second image will keep its default width, while the image in the `.alon div` will take the width of its parent container. In this case, the image in the `.alon div` is taking 100% width of the browser, and the image within is taking 100% width of the `.alon div`.

I've included an example below that applies 100% width to the second image as well.

```
body img {
width: 100%;
}
```

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.alon  {
    width: 100%;
    border: 5px solid green;
    padding: 0px;
}

.alon img {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
}

body img {
width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="alon">
       <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/10/28/11/08/castle-5693094__340.jpg" alt="">
</div>

<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/10/28/11/08/castle-5693094__340.jpg">
```

After running the code you will notice that the second image takes 100% width of the browser like your first image.

If you delete the following CSS:

```
body img {
width: 100%;
}
```

The second image will go back to its default size.

Additionally, to further answer your question, since your first image is enclosed in a div that has a 5px green border, the default [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) on a browser will not calculate your border as part of the declared width of 100%, which in turn, will offset your image container by 5px.

To make the browser calculate the 5px border as part of the container width of 100% you can apply a universal `box-sizing: border-box` to your document.

I've included this in the snippet above for reference.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer ! 

It think I was not clear.

 I didn't want to make the second image as 100% of the width.

My question is -
Why if I drop an image in the body, and I don't specify anything in the css - 
Why it is caused the first image, which set to 100% - to not take 100% when the browser was smaller? What happend was that with the add on of the second image, after cerating px, the first image didn't take 100% anymore, it shrinked down.

Comment: If the first image had a width of 100%, and the parent div around the first image also had a width of 100%, then there is no reason why the first image wouldn't take the width of its parent div. - If what you say is true then the document body must not be 100% width of the browser but I have created an example from the code you provided and showed you why this isn't the case. - Feel free to update your code and show the actual example of what you are experiencing.